# Bones rotate instead of moving; I tried fixing it and changing it to keep offset

Tags: rigging

This is my first time rigging a model. When I was trying to move the bone, it rotates. Instead, I tried changing the bones to keep offset, but when I moved the bone, all the model's parts all changed direction to where that one bone is but didn't stick to the other bones.

[image: Before]

[image: Before]

[image: After]

[image: After]

Comment: Welcome to BSE. Unfortunately you haven't provided enough details or any images for us to even guess what your problem might be. Please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/313947/edit) your question and add screenshots of Blender's screen before and after moving your bone. You can take Screenshots in Blender via the Window > Save Screenshot menu.

Comment: Hello, Slider, I have to agree with @JohnEason.. at the moment this post is vulnerable to closure as 'unclear'. Please try to  reduce your problem to one representative example of what's going wrong. A picture would help a lot, and you can share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/ ..

Comment: do anyone know how to solve this ?, im still waiting for a answer.

Comment: This post is unclear, but the bones usually rotate instead of moving when they are connected.  Bone > Relations > Uncheck the "Connected" option.